# Using colors stored as variables in vimscript?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to import variables set in another .vim file and use them in my script.

The fist script `colors-wal.vim`

```
" Special
let wallpaper  = "cyb285r5j1w31.png"
let background = "#020303"
let foreground = "#e2cdc2"
let cursor     = "#e2cdc2"

" Colors
let color0  = "#020303"
let color1  = "#B09747"
let color2  = "#A1A958"
let color3  = "#ACB258"
let color4  = "#D09B60"
let color5  = "#E8D36E"
let color6  = "#D7AF94"
let color7  = "#e2cdc2"
let color8  = "#9e8f87"
let color9  = "#B09747"
let color10 = "#A1A958"
let color11 = "#ACB258"
let color12 = "#D09B60"
let color13 = "#E8D36E"
let color14 = "#D7AF94"
let color15 = "#e2cdc2"
```

"My" script taken from wal.vim and updated to work with termguicolors

```
hi clear
set background=dark

if exists('syntax_on')
syntax reset
endif

" Colorscheme name
let g:colors_name = 'wal-test'

source ~/.cache/wal/colors-wal.vim

let g:theTest=color1

hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guifg=color7 ctermfg=7
hi NonText ctermbg=NONE guifg=color0 ctermfg=0
hi Comment ctermbg=NONE guifg=color8 ctermfg=8
hi Conceal ctermbg=NONE
hi Constant ctermbg=NONE guifg=color3 ctermfg=3
hi Error guibg=color1 ctermbg=1 guifg=color7 ctermfg=7
hi Identifier ctermbg=NONE guifg=color1 ctermfg=1 gui=BOLD cterm=BOLD
hi Ignore guibg=color8 ctermbg=8 guifg=color0 ctermfg=0
hi PreProc ctermbg=NONE guifg=color3 ctermfg=3
```

I truncated the script and removed most comments, but there are no errors given by Vim and its just more of the same. The colorscheme is set properly because when I unset it I get nvims native color scheme.

`:echo theTest` Returns `#B09747`

`:hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guifg=#B09747 ctermfg=7` changes the normal text color as expected.

`:hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guifg=theTest ctermfg=7` does "nothing", it will unset the command above.

I am not sure what exactly to try. I though maybe concatenation, so i did `guifg= . theTest`, but it returns an error that says E416: missing equal sign, which I have looked up, but am maybe to novice to understand. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Unless there is another way, it must be run as a script in order to substitute the variable meaningfully.

For example

`:hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guifg=theTest ctermfg=7`

should be

`:execute "hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guifg=" . theTest . " ctermfg=7"`